# MYSQL Query Issue in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

High friends,

could you please help me to check date from datetime on mysql query in codeigniter

like

```
return $this->db->select("*")->from($this->db->dbprefix."notification")->where('date',date('Y-m-d'))->get()->result();
```

in database date is in this format date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
i am also trying by using like it is not working for me 
please anybody help me

Answer (score 0):

Hi you just need to use DATE function in mysql column

Try these one

```
return $this->db->select("*")->from($this->db->dbprefix."notification")->where('DATE(date)',date('Y-m-d'))->get()->result();
```

Comment: Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use this:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ".$this->db->prefix('notification')." WHERE DATE(date) = ".date('Y-m-d'));
$query->result();
```

If you need help regarding this please comment below.